# How many ways can 6 pairs of 2 pegs be arranged in 12 holes… discarding duplicates read in opposite direction (re: music theory)

Tags: combinatorics, music-theory

I hope it’s OK for a non-mathematician (a musician) to ask a question here. My question is actually about music, but I’ve dressed it in plain clothes.

Suppose you have a line of 12 equally-spaced holes, and 6 sets of 2 pegs. The pegs are indistinguishable from each other, but each pair is connected by a stretchy (virtual) rubber band, stretchy enough so that any pair of pegs can sit in any pair of holes. The line of holes runs left to right. My question is: how many different ways can all 6 pairs of pegs be arranged in the 12 holes such that every pattern/arrangement of pegs/rubber bands is unique, **also** taking into account that where a pattern read from left to right is the same as a pattern read from right to left, then the two patterns are considered equivalent, and count as one pattern only, not two?

Ideally, I’m looking for the general case: *h* holes, *s* sets of *p* pegs, where *h* = *s* x *p*

Leaving aside left/right equivalence—I guess the number of ways in which the 6 pairs of 2 pegs can be arranged in 12 holes = 11x9x7x5x3 = 10,395 —equivalent to: *h*! / (*p*^*s* x *s*!)   Is that correct?

If so, then the answer I’m looking for is 10,395 minus the number of times there exist two arrangements such that in one arrangement the pattern of pairs of pegs read left to right is the same as in another arrangement when read from right to left. Is there a way of finding this number without comparing 10,395 arrangements?

I see this could be answered by writing a program that compares left and right patterns — but is there a maths solution for this? One a lay-person could usefully employ?

Apologies if the question is long-winded - when I try to precis it gets less clear, I think.

Thanks so much!

Padraic
[Drawing of counting method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyDY1.jpg)

Comment: Can you explain the rubber bands? Do they constrain placement of the pegs in any way? Are you saying that each pair of pegs should be distinct from the others, but within a pair the pegs can't be distinguished?

Comment: Thanks for the question. No, the 'rubber bands' do not constrain in any way. They are included in the description only to make clear (!?) that the pairs of pegs remain 'pairs'.  I couldn't think of how else to convey this.

Comment: Ok I think I understand your question and I'll answer below.

Comment: Best way I can think of explaining is that it's all about the patterns of pairs across the 12 holes. But neither the individual pegs comprising the pairs, nor which pair fits where - are relevant. Does that clarify?

Comment: See  my answer and let me know if I interpreted your question correctly

Answer (score 1):

The pairs of pegs with rubber bands can be thought of as labeling each pair, so in your example we could say we have 12 pegs labelled A,A,B,B,C,C,D,D,E,E,F,F. We want to know how many distinct words can be written in these letters, where two words are equivalent if they are reflections of each other. First without this equivalence the answer would be $\frac{12!}{2^{6}}$. There are $12!$ ways to order $12$ distinct objects, and then for each pair we've over-counted by a factor of 2, since for each word swapping any pair of pegs gives an equivalent word.

Now we can think about the equivalence. Think about reflecting a word through its center: ABACBF|EDDCFE $\rightarrow$ EFCDDE|FBCABA. Let $W$ be the set of all words before equivalence. Let $X$ be the set of words up to equivalence (so a pair of reflected words is one element). Let $P$ be the set of palindromes (words that are the same read forwards and backwards). Palindromes are exactly the words that are unchanged by reflection through the center. Now using [Burnside's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) we have:

$$|X| = \frac{|W| + |P|}{2}$$

where putting the set in bars means the size of the set. We know $|W| = \frac{12!}{2^{6}}$ and we want to know $|X|$, so we just need to count $|P|$. To count palindromes we need to place $6$ distinct letters down in any order, and then the last $6$ letters are forced. For example if we pick ACBFED we get the palindrome ACBFED|DEFBCA. There are $6!$ ways to do this, so $|P| = 6!$. We then have $$|X| = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{12!}{2^{6}} + 6!\right)$$.

In general with $s$ sets of $p$ pegs we can still count $|W|$ as $|W| = \frac{(s\cdot p)!}{p!^s}$ since now we over count by a factor of $p!$ rearrangements for each set $s$ of pegs. To count |P| we can do something similar to before as well. If there is only 1 set of pegs then $|X| = 1$, and from now on we'll assume there's more than 1 set of pegs. If $p$ is odd and there is more than 1 set of pegs we can't have any palindromes, so $|X| = \frac{|W|}{2} =\frac{(s\cdot p)!}{2(p!^s)}$. If $p$ is even, then from each set of pegs half of the pegs will be in the left half of the word, and the other half reflected on the right half. We need to count distinct left halves, which are words of length $\frac{s\cdot p}{2}$ using $s$ sets of $\frac{p}{2}$ letters. There are $\frac{\left(\frac{s\cdot p}{2}\right)!}{\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)!^s}$ of these. We get: $$|X| =\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{(s\cdot p)!}{p!^s} + \frac{\left(\frac{s\cdot p}{2}\right)!}{\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)!^s}\right)$$

Comment: Wow!  This is fabulous -- can't tell you how much I appreciate it. I've read it twice, and I think I understand... but it'll take me a little while to fully understand. Thank you!! :)  :)  And I will say more when I do!

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped. This type of counting shows up a lot in music theory. You might like to read [this](http://www.mtosmt.org/issues/mto.07.13.4/mto.07.13.4.hook.pdf) article by Dr. Hook. He explains the idea I used starting at the bottom of page 8, and there's a lot of other good stuff in there.

Comment: Thanks so much! In fact I downloaded that article about a week ago, but hadn't made my way through it yet, so it's now top of the list. Hugely appreciate the clarity of your explanation above - it's very clear how you've written this for a non-mathematician. I'm struggling with a few bits, but will try to work it out before asking any further questions! I'm 99.99% sure you understood exactly what I was asking.

Comment: If pegs are all identical (I.e. A,B,C etc can all be permuted without changing the peg-string arrangements) then I believe you need to further divide by $6!$ for you example case.

Comment: Thanks N Shales, I find the first step confusing. It seems like there are two approaches.  (1) Place the 1st peg in the left-most hole, then there are 11 places to put the 2nd peg; wherever you place the 3rd peg, there are 9 places to put the 4th peg. Continuing like this gives 11x9x7x5x3 = 10,395. (2) place the 1st peg in any of 12 holes, and the 2nd in any of 11 holes, but we’ve double-counted so divide by 2 = (12x11)/2. Following the pattern gives ((12x11)/2) x ((10x9)/2)… = 12!/(2^6) = 7484400. So I feel stupid I can't see which is the right method... Now looking at the article..

Comment: Hi @Padraic, you have to use @[user] if you want people to get the notification of your comment (if it is not their question or answer). Anyhoo, both answers are valid depending on whether pegs are distinguishable or not, aside from pairs that is. Since there are $6$ pairs there is a factor of $6!$ difference in the count. Honestly I thought you would have had most trouble with Burnside's Lemma since it relies on some knowledge of group theory. This is a good answer but if you want indistinguishable pegs then you need to divide out the $6!$ permutations of A through F.

Comment: rVitale and  @N.Shales – your answer & comments all appreciated! I don’t fully understand Burnside’s Lemma yet, but I can see from Wiki it’s a formula to count objects, where two things related by symmetry (here reflection) are not to be counted as distinct; and the equation makes sense to me. However, I’m still not 100% about the first step (as explained above), so I’ve drawn a diagram of how I’m counting. I see other people post pictures: should I do this as an ‘answer’??  Thanks

Comment: Also, I noticed the up arrow on the left ‘this is useful’.  I’d like to click that, but only haven’t because maybe the buttons are ‘exclusive’ (?) and you can’t back-track – and actually this answer is the solution?  Excuse the noobiness.

Comment: Would also like to say how much I learned from your answer- in terms of how to approach these problems, and how certain 'moves' can be combined to achieve a result. The Hook article is useful, but I should probably buy a book of essential techniques in combinatorics as I have a lot of work to complete in this area and ought to be doing it as independently as I can. Could you possibly recommend one?

Comment: @Padraic if you could edit your original post with a picture of how you're counting or maybe the musical description of what you're trying to do I can help clarify the first step. I assumed you wanted to consider each set of pegs as distinct.

Comment: @rVitale Thanks - I just tried to paste a drawing, but recieved message saying I'm not allowed to do that yet, but would provide a link.  Hope you can see it.

Comment: The pegs and rubber band now look like staples of different lengths, reading vertically rather than left to right, ordered by always choosing the smallest staple that avoids repeating a previous permutation. 

Each of 1 to 15 (and on…) are to be counted as one instance - not 6 factorial.  My question: that being the case, I wonder if N Shales is correct?  Apologies, I find this quite hard to decipher!

Comment: @rVitale BTW -- 4 (and 16… not shown) are rotations of 2.  7 (and 31…) are rotations of 3.  However rotations are not considered equivalent in this universe [because I’m working on a project concerning music theory which dispenses with octave equivalence; further, the staples represent placeholders for intervallic classes, not pitch-classes].  

The brackets at the top (‘seagulls’) mark how the permutations—ordered as described, and from 3 onwards—seem naturally to fall in threes. Probably not immediately relevant, but seemed of interest...

Comment: I would recommend [Applied Combinatorics](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://gettextbook.download/Math%2520180/Applied%2520Combinatorics,%2520Tucker,%25206th.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwism-O8l6TTAhWqAcAKHcTfApkQFggeMAA&usg=AFQjCNGOTG7A61pDlSOrNbKjvKwOqu3MDA&sig2=pzyK7BSNnj4HrcmWrk8Rew) by Alan Tucker. I think this has the most straightforward treatment of Burnside's lemma I've ever seen. Many pure mathematics would probably disagree but I found it to be sufficiently engaging that I could read it like a novel. Plus, it's free! Have you *seen* the Amazon price?!

Comment: @N. Shales -- Thanks - that's fantastic! Indeed, seemingly crazy prices for academic texts these days... music too.

Comment: @Padraic ah ok yea it looks like you're doing something different than my answer and the sets are not considered distinct.  I'll try to update my answer when I get a chance

Comment: @rVitale - thanks very much. I think that's correct - it's not like each staple/pair of pegs is a different colour from the others, or something like that. Likewise hoping to find time to work thru Chapter 5 of the Tucker book, and sharpen my sense of this. I imagine your answer is correct except for the initial counting, for which I need simply to substitute my initial count - but please do tell me if this is wrong! Have been trying to find a way of being sure for myself but haven't succeeded yet...

Comment: @N.Shales – at risk of making a complete fool of myself: Tucker, p.84, Example 4 – should the answer be 52 rather than 53? Hasn’t he over-counted by one ‘zero-fruit’?! I tremble to put this as an independent question! :)

Comment: @N.Shales - Very sorry, p.184.

Comment: @N.Shales - Oh no, found my mistake. I am being a nuisance. Won't happen again. Sorry.